# Ideas on how to pass the HttpRequest from classic ASP page to an ASP.NET MVC action?

Tags: web-services, soap, asp-classic, vbscript

I have a classic ASP page that was implemented in 2002-ish.
It was acting as an exposed entry point for a collection of SOAP web services.

All this page has is the VB script to create a  SoapServer30 object, load a WSDL and WSML and send the object the HttpRequest in order to invoke the web service method.

The web service method is being specified in the HTTP Header's SOAPAction variable.
The request also contains the SOAP envelope with the parameters for the web service call.

This process is no longer working due to changes in the WSDL, the deployment changes, etc.
Basically it's too far gone and too much change has happened since 2002 to salvage this process.

We have a client though that does not want to make any code changes, they use Axis and Java to create the web service request and call this ASP page.
I'd like to alter the VB script to simply pass the HttpRequest to an ASP.NET MVC page for parsing and to route to the correct web service.
Then I'll simply return the result.

Any and all code samples would be greatly appreciated as I have little to no experience with VBScript. My experience is in C#.NET.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need VBScript at all any more? Why not simply create an ASP.NET MVC route that takes the request directly? I think the ASP.NET MVC route could simply have the same name as the old .asp file.

Comment: I think you're right, I think that can work. Because it's simply being passed through the HttpRequest. And I can access that in the MVC context. I'm not too familiar with setting up custom MVC routing to mimic something like MyPage.ASP, but I'll start looking into that.
Thanks for the good idea.

Comment: Update: Got it routed correctly using:


routes.MapRoute(
                "Page",
                "MyPage.ASP",
                new { controller = "Test", action = "KTASP", id = "" }
            );


Now I just have to deploy it, and I should be good to parse the SOAP envelope out of the HttpRequest and do what I need to do. 

Thanks again!